# How to set environment variables in Jenkins

Tags: python, windows, jenkins, environment-variables

I have this error:

'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I have defined environment variables like this to sort it out:
[image: Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> environment variables]

But this results in this error:
'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

In order to solve this I add Path{} in script like this;

```
pipeline {
   agent any
   environment {

    PATH = "C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32"

}
   stages {
      stage('Hello') {
         steps {
            echo "Hello World"
            bat "python E:/airflowtmp/hello.py"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This results in first error again. How do I solve this?

Comment: append `;%PATH%`  to the  value of `path` environment in your screenshot

Answer (score -1):

You can add Python path also in your environment variables if it's not there.
For example: set PATH=%PATH%;C:\python271\
Can you please check what is the parent directory path of python installation.This can be checked from windows environment variable path.Or else, from command prompt, we can get it using echo %path%". Then please check, whether u have given this path in jenkins - > manage jenkins -> Configure System -> Environment variables. Please restart Jenkins service once you make the changes.

Comment: C:\Users\fatima.arshad\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2 Paths that I added in screenshot are the same as that added in system.

Comment: I execute conda --version as well as python in local cmd and it is working fine

Comment: One more thing, you can try. As the python is working from local, I am assuming that you should able to run that python script from local. So you can create one bat file, put your python script inside that and then call the bat file from jenkins.

Comment: bat file content can be c:\python27\python.exe c:\somescript.py